# How to retrive all classes from package in android project?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to retrieve all classes from model packge in android project but unable to get please share any suggetion or solution .

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve all classes from model packge"?

Comment: using packge name i want to retrieve all classes which are included in packge programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help-

Use `import <package_name>.*`. `*` will allow to access all classes of that package

Comment: thanks for reply ...i want to get names of all classes which are in model package